# How to set full width for div when hover ?- navbar dropdown - Angular - Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to set full width for the div. since its has slideDown/Up effect i could catch exact css to change its width.

So far I've below snippet.

i could able to see class `open` which is dynamically appending to div when hover it. but i don't how to set full width for that div.

```js
$(".dropdown").hover(
  function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideDown("400");
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  },
  function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp("400");
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <div class="nav-item dropdown dropdown-slide dropdown-hover">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">slide down to see</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu row" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">First Item</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Second One</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">The last but not the least</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Is that any possible to have the same effect with pure CSS without using jquery?

I've tried lots of SO css threat but couldn't find exactly what im looking for

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to make it fullwidth.

I have added a new class `fullwidth` to `dropdown` and modified some properties. Hope this will help :)

```js
$(".dropdown").hover(
  function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideDown("400");
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  },
  function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp("400");
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  }
);
```

```css
.fullwidth.dropdown {
  position: static;
}

.fullwidth .dropdown-menu {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <div class="nav-item dropdown dropdown-slide dropdown-hover fullwidth">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">slide down to see</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu row" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">First Item</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Second One</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">The last but not the least</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes exactly . but some times flickering when trying move cursor on li elemnts. is this because of height?

Comment: Its not related to this. Its because the empty space between dropown the menu